# Get Beacon Diagnostics

Tags: google-beacon-platform

I an unable to reliably get responses from the API for [Beacon Monitoring](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/monitor). About 10% of the time, a request to `/v1beta1/beacons/<beaconId>/diagnostics` will succeed (although it always takes upwards of 10-20 seconds to respond). The remainder of the time, I see the following `504` response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 504,
    "message": "Deadline expired before operation could complete.",
    "status": "DEADLINE_EXCEEDED"
  }
}
```

Is this a known issue with the API, or is there something improperly configured with my beacon instances?

Comment: What's the (scrubbed, of course) query you're running?

Comment: Literally just `https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beacons/-/diagnostics` to get diagnostics for all beacons. In the past few days, the occurrence of the error has dropped a lot. I still see it occasionally. However, the rest of the time, this specific query takes an order of magnitude longer than the others. Most requests come back in <1s…this one always takes 10-15s.

Comment: have you had any luck with getting any diagnostics information?